# Making the timestep of Euler method integration a variable

Tags: functions, physics

I am fairly new to Mathematica, and I've been trying to implement the Euler method of integration for a fluid velocity field. I can't work out how to make the timestep a variable of my Euler method function.

The code that I have for the Euler method is:

```
h = 0.01;
F[{x_, y_}] := {-y/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) - y/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2), (x - 0.7)/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) + (x + 0.7)/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2)}; (*defining the two components of the flow field*)
G[{x_, y_}] := {x, y} + {F[{x, y}][[1]], F[{x, y}][[2]]}*h; (*Euler's method for a single timestep, h is the timestep*)
EulerMethod[x0_, y0_, Nsteps_] := NestList[G, {x0, y0}, Nsteps] (*Iterating Euler's method for a number of steps Nsteps, starting from the initial conditions (x0, y0)*)
```

Currently, I can only work out how to set h manually, as in the code above.

I would like to be able to make h a variable of EulerMethod[], so that I can adjust the timestep. If anybody has any ideas as to how I could do this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to make h a variable of EulerMethod[],

You could do

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
F[{x_, y_}] := {-y/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) - 
    y/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2), (x - 0.7)/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) + (x + 
       0.7)/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2)};
G[{x_, y_, h_}] := Flatten[{{x, y} + {F[{x, y}][[1]], F[{x, y}][[2]]}*h, h}];
EulerMethod[x0_, y0_, Nsteps_, h_?NumericQ] := NestList[G, {x0, y0, h}, Nsteps]
```

And now

```
result=EulerMethod[0,1,4,0.01];
(result[[All,1;;2]])//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This gives same result as your code, but now you can pass `h` as argument.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
h = 0.01;
F[{x_, y_}] := {-y/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) - 
    y/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2), (x - 0.7)/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) + (x + 
       0.7)/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2)};
G[{x_, y_}] := {x, y} + {F[{x, y}][[1]], F[{x, y}][[2]]}*h;
EulerMethod[x0_, y0_, Nsteps_] := NestList[G, {x0, y0}, Nsteps] ;
EulerMethod[0, 1, 4]//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it works perfectly! I wanted to plot the solution using ListPlot, so to get rid of the values of h output by EulerMethod I used `ListPlot[Drop[EulerMethod[0.1, 0.1, 1000, 0.01], None, {3}], 
 Joined -> True]`, and the graphs I made match those I was getting previously.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

F[{x_, y_}] = {-y/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) - 
     y/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2), (x - 0.7)/((x - 0.7)^2 + y^2) + (x + 
        0.7)/((x + 0.7)^2 + y^2)} // Rationalize;
```

Note that `{F[{x, y}][[1]], F[{x, y}][[2]]} === F[{x, y}]`

```
G[{x_, y_}, h : _?NumericQ : 1/100] := {x, y} + F[{x, y}]*h;

EulerMethod[x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, Nsteps_Integer?Positive, 
  h : _?NumericQ : 1/100] := NestList[G[#, h] &, {x0, y0}, Nsteps]

n = 20;

ListPlot[{EulerMethod[.7, .6, n], EulerMethod[.7, .6, n, 1/200]},
 PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"]
```

[image]